# How do you sort a generator type with 1.72e+10 elements in python according to 2nd "column"?

Tags: python

I have a generator object containing 2 "columns" and 1.72e+10 "rows". I want to sort the generator object according to the second column, using sorted like this takes an insane amount of time. I don't know if it makes sense to talk about columns and rows in generators, but I use quotations marks as I don't know what else to call it.

```
sorted_list = sorted(list(generator_obj),
                     key=lambda x: x[1], 
                         reverse=True)
```

Is there any smart way of sorting a huge generator object quickly? I don't have a computer science background, so I guess I am also wondering if it is inevitable to spend a huge amount of time on sorting such a large object? Also I believe it is faster to convert the `generator_obj` before supplying it as an argument for `sorted()`, which is why I don't submit a raw generator.

I have also tried to sort in place with the same results as above:

```
list(generator_obj).sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorting requires `~N log N` time, if all you have is a comparison function.

If your keys are integers, you can sort in `~ N` time using the [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).

Either way, sorting a "huge" sequence requires "huge" time.